# Python C Extension with Multiple Functions

Tags: python, ctypes, setuptools

I'm currently learning how to create C extensions for Python so that I can call C/C++ code. I've been teaching myself with a few examples. I started with [this guide](https://nesi.github.io/perf-training/python-scatter/ctypes) and it was very helpful for getting up and running. All of the guides and examples I've found online only give C code where a single function is defined. I'm planning to access a C++ library with multiple functions from Python and so I decided the next logical step in learning would be to add more functions to the example.

However, when I do this, only the first function in the extension is accessible from Python. Here's the example that I've made for myself (for reference I'm working on Ubuntu 21):

The C code (with two functions: `func1` and `func2`, where `func1` also depends on `func2`) and header files:

```cpp
//func1.cpp

extern "C"

#include "func1.h"

double func1(double x, double y, double z) {
    return x*x + y*y + z*z*z + func2(x,y,z);
}

double func2(double x, double y, double z) {
    return x*y*z;
}
```

```cpp
//func1.h

double func1(double x, double y, double z);
double func2(double x, double y, double z);
```

Then the Python extension setup which is run with `python setup.py build`:

```py
#setup.py

from setuptools import setup, Extension

setup(
    ext_modules=[Extension('func1', sources=['func1.cpp'], include_dirs=['func1.h'])]
)
```

And finally the Python script where the extension is used which is run with `python example.py`:

```py
#example.py

import ctypes
import numpy
import glob


libfile = glob.glob('build/*/func1*.so')[0]

lib = ctypes.CDLL(libfile)
func1 = lib.func1
func2 = lib.func2

func1.restype = ctypes.c_double
func1.argtypes = [ctypes.c_double, ctypes.c_double, ctypes.c_double]

func2.restype = ctypes.c_double
func2.argtypes = [ctypes.c_double, ctypes.c_double, ctypes.c_double]


print( func1(2,3,4) )
print( func2(2,3,4) )
```

When I do this example, `python setup.py build` compiles fine. However, when I get run the example file with `python example.py` I get that following error and traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/Desktop/c_extension_example/example.py", line 12, in <module>
    func2 = lib.func2
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/ctypes/__init__.py", line 387, in __getattr__
    func = self.__getitem__(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/ctypes/__init__.py", line 392, in __getitem__
    func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
AttributeError: build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/func1.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: func2
```

Which indicates that the function `func2` isn't accessible through the extension. However, if I remove the references to `func2` in `example.py` then everything runs fine and I get a result from `func1` that is correct.

This is interesting to me because `func1` depends on `func2`, but I can't access `func2` directly. How can I change this example such that I can also access `func2`? Do I need to make a separate file and extension for each function that I want to access? That would be a bit cumbersome if I want to make an extension for a large C library.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `export "C"` include both functions:

```cpp
#include "func1.h"

extern "C" {

double func1(double x, double y, double z) {
    return x*x + y*y + z*z*z + func2(x,y,z);
}

double func2(double x, double y, double z) {
    return x*y*z;
}

}
```

```
extern "C" {

double func1(double x, double y, double z);
double func2(double x, double y, double z);

}
```

Without the braces, `extern "C"` is only applied to the next declaration, which is `double func1(double x, double y, double z);`.

Comment: @matthews. Actually, `func2` was exported, but with a [C++ "mangled" name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#C++): `_Z5func2ddd`. This is done because of overloading by parameter types.